# Cannot delete SQL Server project file?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have a .ssmssqlproj file in a Sharepoint folder, but I cannot delete it. It says that some application may currently use it. That is not true, because I don't have SSMS open. How to delete this SQL Server Management Studio project file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tools like [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) (use the "find handle or dll" function) will tell you what processes have a file open (with delete lock). This allows you to know what to close to allow deleting.